# Playwright delay, hang, never resolve response with route (add latency)

Tags: async-await, wait, playwright

I need to test service when response is delayed or is never resolved. Done brute force implementation:

```js
await page.route(url, () => page.waitForTimeout(1000));
```

As docs says: `page.waitForTimeout()` should only be used for debugging  [link](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-timeout)

But how to i.e. make page request for url, and wait till page receives timeout.

Another scenario:

- Page requesting data i.e. api/items
- I need to check page state before api/items request is resolved

Dummy test example:

```js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('banner shows in progress message', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.route('**/async-resource.json', () => {
     // this request should not be resolved before tests ends 
     page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  });

  await page.goto('https://async.page/');
  const banner = page.getByRole('banner');
  await expect(banner).toHaveText('Your data are being prepared!');
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? For example `page.goto(url, timeout)` and if we get timeout then assert an error or something?

Comment: @JakyRuby updated question with example

Comment: Are you basically testing for a loading page? You can use `page.waitForTimeout` internally without issue. https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/20562 That test example should do what you're expecting, what isn't working? maybe you need to wrap the two calls inside an array of promise and do `await Promise.all([goto, expect])`

Comment: @A.L Test example indeed works but I wonder if there is some more elegant way of simulating pending request nad not using `page.waitForTimeout(1000);`. There is no official way of doing it in route: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-route